# Como obter o nome do objeto pai da propriedade Javascript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
 var teste = 'objeto': {
           version: '5.x.x',
           name:this[??]  // 'objeto'
        };
```

O que poderia ser feito para que a propriedade `name` tenha o mesmo nome do objeto a quem ele pertence (que no caso é `objeto`)?

Comment: A sintaxe que tens está errada, não podes dar nomes a objetos dessa maneira. Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer?

Comment: Tem certeza que não é `{'objeto':{...}}`  ao invés de `'objeto':{...}`?

Comment: É isso mesmo, não me importei muito com a sintaxe porque o foco é o conceito, mas realmente propriedades em formato de string são apenas aceitas quando dentro de um objeto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma sintaxe especial para fazer o que você está querendo. Objetos em javascript não tem nenhum ponteiro pro "pai" (afinal, se houvesse daria pra notar uma diferença se um objeto está armazenado numa tabela, lista ou variável - seria uma grande dor de cabeça...)

Se o que você quer é evitar de escrever a string "objeto" duas vezes, algo que você pode fazer é por esse nome numa variável e atribuir campos dinâmicamente:

```
var myName = 'objeto';
var teste = {};
teste[myName] = {version: '5.x.x', name:myName}
```